# How to remove description from chart in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

How can I remove the description from `PieChart`?
I can remove the `Legend` with `chart.setDrawLegend(false)`, but I couldn't find anything regarding the chart description in the documentation.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Do you mean the **description** which is in the bottom right corner (default) of the `Chart`?

If so, simply call:

`chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);`

Or did you mean the **textual description** inside the pie-slices?

`pieChart.setDrawSliceText(false);`

Or did you mean the actual **slice values** inside the pie-slices?

`pieData.setDrawValues(false);`

Or are you talking about the [Legend](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/legend/) (shows all `DataSet` labels and colors outside of the chart)?

`chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);`

This answer is based on [release v3.0.0+](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases), for more information check out the [**documentation**](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation).

Comment: The text at the bottom left corner.. Just below the BarChart. :(

Comment: that's what i needed : chart.setDrawSliceText(false); 
thx for saving my time :)

Comment: @PhilippJahoda Is there any way to show negative values or negative lables (slice values) in piechart??

Comment: Your class class apart :)

Comment: For textual description, use the new way `chart.setDrawEntryLabels(false);`

Comment: binding.radarChart.legend.isEnabled = false. it is working for me

Answer (score 11):

In the new version you can do it like this:

```
Description des = Chart.getDescription();
des.setEnabled(false);
```

If you want to remove the legend:

```
Legend leg = Chart.getLegend();
leg.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 5):

## you can remove it by simply passing null into it.

pieChart.setDescription(null);

Answer (score 5):

in kotlin use

```
chart.description.isEnabled = false
```