# When I use mpAndroidChart i found the bottom label haven't show

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to remove the description in [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). I don't know where the description comes from, here is a pic
[image]

And here is what I want to，I think there should have two labels,
I set it by:

```
LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(y1,"dataSet1");
```

[image]

here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LineChart lineChart;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lineChart=(LineChart)findViewById(R.id.main_chart);
        ArrayList<String> xAXES = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Entry> y1=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Entry> y2 =new ArrayList<>();
        double x=0;
        int numdatapoint=10;
        for (int i = 0; i <numdatapoint ; i++) {
            float sinfunction = i;
            float confunction =i+2;
            x=x+0.1;
            y1.add(new Entry(sinfunction,i-1));
            y2.add(new Entry(confunction,i+2));
            xAXES.add(i,String.valueOf(i));
        }
        String [] xaxes =new String [xAXES.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i <xAXES.size() ; i++) {
            xaxes[i]=xAXES.get(i).toString();
        }
        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> lineDataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(y1,"dataSet1");
        lineDataSet.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        LineDataSet lineDataSetY = new LineDataSet(y2,"dataset2");
        lineDataSet.setColor(Color.RED);
        lineDataSets.add(lineDataSet);
        lineDataSets.add(lineDataSetY);
        LineData line =new LineData();
        lineChart.setData(new LineData(lineDataSets));
        lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10f);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have set the position of the X-Axis to the top?

You can change this by using the `setPosition(XAxisPosition pos);` function (Sets the position where the XAxis should appear. Choose between TOP, BOTTOM, BOTH_SIDED, TOP_INSIDE or BOTTOM_INSIDE.)

Reference: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/XAxis

Edit:
Looks like you're after the Legend?
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Legend

Comment: its not ,i just want to have two label,the bottom  should have two label,set by  LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(y1,"son");,but its disappear

Comment: i have set lineChart.getLegend().setEnabled(true);  but its still not change,and legend not appear

Answer (score 0):

Here is your above code with correction and running perfectly you can find and run in your project.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{ 
    LineChart lineChart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainchart);
        lineChart=(LineChart)findViewById(R.id.line_chart);
        ArrayList<String> xAXES = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Entry> y1=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Entry> y2 =new ArrayList<>();
        double x=0;
        int numdatapoint=2;

        for (int i = 0; i <numdatapoint ; i++) {
            float sinfunction = i;
            float confunction =i+2;
            x=x+0.1;
            y1.add(new Entry(sinfunction,i-1));
            y2.add(new Entry(confunction,i+2));
            xAXES.add(i,String.valueOf(i));
        }
        String [] xaxes =new String [xAXES.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i <xAXES.size() ; i++) {
            xaxes[i]=xAXES.get(i).toString();
        }
        List<ILineDataSet> lineDataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(y1,"dataSet1");
        lineDataSet.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        LineDataSet lineDataSetY = new LineDataSet(y2,"dataset2");
        lineDataSetY.setColor(Color.RED);
        lineDataSets.add(lineDataSet);
        lineDataSets.add(lineDataSetY);
        LineData data = new LineData(xAXES,lineDataSets);
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        data.setValueTextSize(9f);

        // set data
        lineChart.setData(data);
        lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10f);}}
```

and XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/line_chart"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: there are no method of new LineData(xAXES,lineDataSets);

Comment: will you share the dependency you probably used in your project.The constructer i have used in mentioned in the class LineData

Comment: when i set lineChart.getLegend().setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART); its ok, but it cant be bottom,so weird,but thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try the below line of code;**

```
lineChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
```

[Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566916/how-to-remove-description-from-chart-in-mpandroidchart)