# MPAndroidChart in android

Tags: android, pie-chart

Hi i am new for android and present i am using MPAndroidChart for showing Piechart,By default there are showing some color pickers with some text below of my pie-chart as like my below screen

My screen looks like below after developed the App,But my problem is i don't want to show that color picker's with text below of that pie-chart,

I shared my screen please help me how can i remove them

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove description from Pie Chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566916/remove-description-from-pie-chart)

Comment: Disable legends its done mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

Answer (score 0):

Try using in Kotlin

```
 chart.description.isEnabled = false
 chart.legend.isEnabled = false
```

or in Java

```
 chart.getFescription.setEnabled(false)
 chart.getLegend.setEnabled(false)
```